# Problema con galeria php

Tags: php, imagen

Soy principiante en PhP y estoy haciendo una galería de imágenes con PhP (para facilitar la construcción del div que contiene las imágenes y aplica los estilos).

Este es el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Prueba de codigo</title>

</head>
<body class="bg-info">

  <section class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <h1 class="text-white mt-5">Galería de imágenes</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <?php

        $directorio = opendir("images"); //ruta actual
        while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)) //obtenemos un archivo y luego otro sucesivamente
        {
            if (is_dir($archivo))//verificamos si es o no un directorio
            {
                 //Aqui se hace algo si no es un directorio, opcional
            }
            else
            {
              //Aqui hacen lo que quieran con cada archivo
                echo "<div class='row justify-content-center'>";

                echo "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 text-center'>";

                echo "<div class='card-columns'>";

                echo "<div class='card'>"; //card con imagen
                echo "<a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal_img'>";
                echo "<img src='images/$archivo' alt='$archivo' class='card-img-top' />";
                echo "</a>"; //cierre link imagen
                echo "</div>"; //cierre card

                echo "<div class='modal fade' id='modal_img' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true' style='z-index: 2000;'>"; //modal de imagen centrada
                echo "<div class='modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered' role='document'>";
                echo "<img src='images/$archivo' alt='$archivo' class='img-fluid rounded' />";
                echo "</div>"; //cierre modal dialog
                echo "</div>"; //cierre modal fade

                echo "</div>"; //cierre card columns

                echo "</div>"; //cierre columna

                echo "</div>"; //cierre row
            }
        }

      ?>

      </div>
    </div>



  </section>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

El código en sí me funciona, pero se me presentan 2 problemas que no se solucionar:

1) Intento hacer que ocupen la estructura que le di con el bootstrap 4 pero no funciona, me quedan las imágenes una abajo de la otra, y quiero que se ordenen hacia los lados primero. Si uso ese modelo de galería solo como HTML me funciona sin problemas.

2) Al hacer click en el modal siempre me sale solo la primera imagen, y evidentemente me gustaría que mostrara la imagen a la que hago click, no tengo idea como hacer eso.

Se ve asi:
[image: Resultado de mi codigo PhP]

Estoy intentando que se vea así:

[image: Resultado que espero/busco lograr]

Nuevamente Gracias a toda la comunidad.

Comment: Intenta usar css y los columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré varios errores en tu código y sugerencias de programación

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Prueba de codigo</title>

</head>

<body class="bg-info">

  <section class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <h1 class="text-white mt-5">Galería de imágenes</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <?php

        $directorio = opendir("images"); //ruta actual
        //Aqui hacen lo que quieran con cada archivo
        $html = '';
        $html.="<div class='row justify-content-center'>";
        $html.="<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 text-center'>";

        while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)) //obtenemos un archivo y luego otro sucesivamente
        {
            if (is_dir($archivo))//verificamos si es o no un directorio
            {
                 //Aqui se hace algo si no es un directorio, opcional
            }
            else
            {          
                $html.="
                <div class='card-columns'>
                  <div class='card'> //card con imagen
                    <a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#img_$archivo'>
                      <img src='images/$archivo' alt='$archivo' class='card-img-top' />
                    </a> //cierre link imagen
                  </div> //cierre card

                  <div class='modal fade' id='img_$archivo' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true' style='z-index: 2000;'> //modal de imagen centrada
                    <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered' role='document'>
                      <img src='images/$archivo' alt='$archivo' class='img-fluid rounded' />
                    </div> //cierre modal dialog
                  </div> //cierre modal fade
                </div>"; //cierre card columns
            }
        }

        $html.="
              </div> //cierre columna
            </div> //cierre row";

        echo $html;

      ?>
```

1. Te daba ese resultado por que cada iteración del while estabas creando un nuevo div con clase "ROW" y eso provoca la apilación hacia abajo junto con el div que controla las columnas, como solo quieres iterar las tarjetas pues solo metí las tarjetas con su respectivo modal y dejé un solo row con el controlador de columnas.
2. Te recomiendo que hagas una sola variable (en este caso $html) para que juntes todo tu HTML y cuando termine su trabajo el PHP puedas imprimir la variable que ya tiene todo concatenado y no hacerle echo a todo.
3. Estas creando un modal por cada iteración, te recomiendo que se cree un solo modal y que se llene con la foto con una petición AJAX, eso de crear muchos modales no está cool, aparte que lo tenías con un solo ID, y nunca te iba a abrir las diferentes imagenes si no solo una (por que solo hay un ID), así que para solucionarlo temporal al ID de la imagen le puse el mismo nombre de la imagen, toma en cuenta que si el nombre de la imagen se repite, no va a resultar como quieres.
4. Si no usas la condición `is_dir($archivo)` cuando retorne TRUE, evitala, es mejor usar `!is_dir($archivo)` y empezar tu código.

Espero te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto ordeno bastante mi código y me ayudo a solucionar el problema del modal, pero sigue ordenándose en filas, hacia abajo, y no en columnas y filas del bootstrap.

Comment: Estimado, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, lo pude solucionar!! era solo cosa de ordenar los div, puse el row y el col afuera, y saque el card-column del while, con eso se arreglo :) Muchas gracias por tu aporte, esta comunidad es genial!

Comment: Que bueno que te sirvió, no te olvides de marcar como correcta esta respuesta para que otros no anden divagando con tu mismo error